# Custom DIP Using InfoPath calling a web service - DIP Unable to Load

Tags: infopath, document-info-panel

I have a Custom Document Information Panel developed in InfoPath 2010 - within which I am calling a Web Service to return a date value from the server. The DIP when opened independently works fine, that is, it calls the Web Service and returns the relevant data.

But when the DIP is published on to the content type and then a new document is created from the SharePoint library, the DIP says " unable to load ".

This is the issue that is being shown:

---

Document Information Panel cannot open a new form.
 The form template associated with this form was moved or cannot be accessed. The form template "Template 1" on your computer has the same form ID as the template associated with the form, but it is from a different location.

Location of the associated form template : http://sharepointserver/SharedDocuments/Forms/ContentType1/template1.xsn

Original location of the form template on your computer: file:///c:\Documents\Template1.xsn.

Make sure you can access the location of the sasociated form template and try opening the form again. If that does not work, ask the form author to update the form.

---

Comment: Please remember to mark your questions as answered if they have solved your problem. This will encourage people to answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Before opening the form from the web uninstall the one you published locally. To do this open InfoPath, locate the form in the backstage view and uninstall it. InfoPath keeps a cache of forms that are installed and matches the location of the form to the one it knows it was published to. This is for security reasons, e.g. copying the form onto another domain